# How to add zero in front of single digit values using REGEX in pentaho

Tags: regex, pentaho

I have the month values in a flat file like

```
Month
  12
  11
   1
   2
   8
  10
```

now i want to add zero in front of single digit values & double digit as same.

output should be like

```
Month
  12
  11
  01
  02
  08
  10
```

This am doing in PENTAHO (I will implement in Replace in string step)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am not aware of PENTAHO. But following `regex` should work for most of the languages

**Match :** `\b([0-9])\b`

**Replace :** `0$1`

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/wS6eY8)

Comment: @BharathRaj I thought it was a file. Updated match pattern. Please check now.

Comment: It is one of the column from a flat file which should be concat to the year column and date column, but while concatenating the month it s unable to identify it as a date like Eg: 13901 it should be like 130901. btw the sol is not working for me

Comment: @BharathRaj Now I get it. This description could have better been posted in question. Try updated solution, possibly my last try of understanding your problem.

Comment: Thanks @jkshah, i got it partially but all the single digits are changing to 01.

Comment: @BharathRaj may be you need `$1` instead of `\1`. whole problem because I don't know your language platform. Try now

Comment: Can u suggest where to learn the Regex.. or suggest me any ebooks

Comment: @BharathRaj Refer to [http://www.regular-expressions.info/](http://www.regular-expressions.info/). Practice and test your regex on [regex101.com](http://regex101.com/)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40694/discussion-between-bharath-raj-and-jkshah)